# stop tinymce loading wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I have recently installed TinyMCE manually on my WordPress install. Everything was working fine until I went to edit a plugin I have installed "All in one Cufon". For some reason, TinyMCE has been included even though I have only included it in the theme.

This is adding formatting to the cufon code and breaking it.

Does anybody know how to prevent TinyMCE loading in the WordPress admin?

I get the following error in firebug:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]   

<p>Cufon.replace('h1', { fontFamily: 'AvantGarde LT Book', h
```

here is my TinyMCE files included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "textareas",
            theme : "simple"
    });
    </script>
```

Thanks, Dan

Comment: How exactly did you install TinyMCE manually? Do you use a plugin, or have you written a plugin for this yourself? Also how do you include it in the theme? Do you attach it to an action hook?

Comment: i have updated my question with the answer to your question. I simply downloaded it from the tinymce site and included it. I have included the above in my theme header.

Comment: Okay, I tested it and couldn't reproduce the error. As I understood you have TinyMCE in the "All in one Cufon"-Page under "Settings" `/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=All-In-OneCufon` right? If you've included the script-tags in your theme's **header.php**  for example in the `<head>` it is practically impossible, as the theme files only load in the frontend. If I'm not right, could you state which files of your wordpress installation you've edited, just to make sure, you didn't end up editing the wrong place.

Comment: That's correct, it happens within the settings page of all in one cufon. I've double checked again and tinymce is only definitely included in theme header. I just don't understand? It was fine... and when i checked today it was getting included!